# pyQt v4 rowsMoved Signal

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt, signals

Im pretty new to Qt and have been trying to create a UI where the user will have rows of information and each row represents a stage in a pipeline. Iam trying to achieve that a user can drag and drop the different rows and that will change the order in which the steps occur.

I have achieved the drag and drop of the rows using :
self.tableView.verticalHeader().setMovable(True)

Iam now trying to get the Signal"rowsMoved" to work but cant seem to get it to work in my custom model and delegate. If anyone knows of a way to get this working or of a way to not use this Signla and use another signal to track which row has moved and where it is now moved to. It will be a great help! :)

Thanks everyone

CODE BELOW

```
class pipelineModel( QAbstractTableModel ):

    def __init_( self ):
        super( pipelineModel, self ).__init__()
        self.stages = []

    # Sets up the population of information in the Model    
    def data( self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole ):

        if (not index.isValid() or not (0 <= index.row() < len(self.stages) ) ):
            return QVariant()

        column = index.column()
        stage = self.stages[ index.row() ]          # Retrieves the object from the list using the row count.

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:                      # If the role is a display role, setup the display information in each cell for the stage that has just been retrieved
            if column == NAME:
                return QVariant(stage.name)
            if column == ID:
                return QVariant(stage.id)
            if column == PREV:
                return QVariant(stage.prev)
            if column == NEXT:
                return QVariant(stage.next)
            if column == TYPE:
                return QVariant(stage.assetType)
            if column == DEPARTMENT:
                return QVariant(stage.depID)
            if column == EXPORT:
                return QVariant(stage.export)
            if column == PREFIX:
                return QVariant(stage.prefix)
            if column == DELETE:
                return QVariant(stage.delete)

        elif role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            pass

        elif role == Qt.TextColorRole:
            pass

        elif role == Qt.BackgroundColorRole:
            pass

        return QVariant()

    # Sets up the header information for the table
    def headerData( self, section, orientation, role = Qt.DisplayRole ):

        if role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:

            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return QVariant( int(Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter))
            return QVariant( int(Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignVCenter))

        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()

        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:        # If Orientation is horizontal then we populate the headings
            if section == ID:
                return QVariant("ID")
            elif section == PREV:
                return QVariant("Previouse")
            elif section == NEXT: 
                return QVariant("Next")
            elif section == NAME:
                return QVariant("Name")
            elif section == TYPE:
                return QVariant("Type")
            elif section == DEPARTMENT:
                return QVariant("Department")
            elif section == EXPORT:
                return QVariant("Export Model")
            elif section == PREFIX:
                return QVariant("Prefix")
            elif section == DELETE:
                return QVariant("Delete")
        return QVariant( int( section + 1 ) )           # Creates the Numbers Down the Vertical Side

    # Sets up the amount of Rows they are
    def rowCount( self, index = QModelIndex() ):
        count = 0
        try:
            count = len( self.stages )
        except:
            pass

        return count

    # Sets up the amount of columns they are
    def columnCount( self, index = QModelIndex() ):
        return 9

    def rowsMoved( self, row, oldIndex, newIndex ):
        print 'ASDASDSA'

# ---------MAIN AREA---------
class pipeline( QDialog ):


    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(pipeline, self).__init__(parent)
        self.stages = self.getDBinfo()                      # gets the stages from the DB and return them as a list of objects

        tableLabel      = QLabel("Testing Table - Custom Model + Custom Delegate")
        self.tableView  = QTableView()              # Creates a Table View (for now we are using the default one and not creating our own)

        self.tableDelegate  = pipelineDelegate()
        self.tableModel     = pipelineModel()

        tableLabel.setBuddy( self.tableView )
        self.tableView.setModel( self.tableModel )
#       self.tableView.setItemDelegate( self.tableDelegate )

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.tableView)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.tableView.verticalHeader().setMovable(True) 

        self.connect(self.tableModel, SIGNAL("rowsMoved( )"), self.MovedRow) # trying to setup an on moved signal, need to check threw the available slots
#       self.connect(self.tableModel, SIGNAL("  rowsAboutToBeMoved(QModelIndex,int,int,QModelIndex ,int)"), self.MovedRow) # trying to setup an on moved signal, need to check threw the available slots
```

Comment: I don't think there's enough info here for anyone to be able to help you. I suggest you either add some cut-down code, or info about any error messages, or anything for someone to go on...

Comment: Can you post some code showing how you are currently trying using the signal?

Comment: Added some code. It basically boils down to how do you use the signal rowsMoved on an QAbstractTableModel, its the one thing I piece im missing, how to track the movement of a row so you can see where it was and where it now is, once it has been moved

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to subclass the QTableView, and overload the rowMoved()  SLOT

```
class MyTableView(QtGui.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTableView, self).__init__(parent)

        self.rowsMoved.connect(self.movedRowsSlot)  

    def rowMoved(self, row, oldIndex, newIndex):
        # do something with these or

        super(MyTableView, self).rowMoved(row, oldIndex, newIndex)

    def movedRowsSlot(self, *args):
        print "Moved rows!", args
```

**Edited** To show both overloading rowMoved slot, and using rowsMoved signal

Comment: hey, the row moved is on the AbstractItemModel which iam using the QAbstractTableModel http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsMoved, if you know of how to get the signla working owuld be awesome, its the one missing piece of the puzzle.

Comment: I think the reason its not working for you is because you are not using the full C signture of the signal in the old way you are connecting. I believe if you use the new form of connecting, then you dont need to specify the whole signature. the old way would have to be like:   SIGNAL("rowsMoved(QModelIndex&,int,int,QModelIndex&,int)") . Check my updated answer. btw im doing this on my phone. havent tested.

Comment: Ahoy man, yeah I tried to do an overload and it didn't seem to work, I think  maybe im doing something wrong *face palm*, need to do some more reading.

Comment: Did connecting to the signal, as per my example, not work either?

Answer (score 0):

> Note: Components connected to this signal use it to adapt to changes in the model's dimensions. **It can only be emitted by the QAbstractItemModel implementation, and cannot be explicitly emitted in subclass code**.

Comment: hey, yeah I read saw that comment, do you have any idea then how i would detect this event.

Comment: Does it really not work to just overload the rowMoved() SLOT like I suggested? Does that SLOT not get called?